# How to transfer multiple data from the same row to Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am following this article and example: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/integrate-excel-data-word-document/

I am experimenting by having rows, letters, and date pulled from Excel to Word into a form:

```vb
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application    
    Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\testing.xlsm")
    
    ThisDocument.row.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,1)
    ThisDocument.letter.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
    ThisDocument.date.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 3)            
    Set exWb = Nothing
End Sub
```

From this Excel 'table':
[image]

To Word, so it looks like this:
[image]

I want if there are multiple rows with the same number (on the picture, you can see that row 3 has three 3s with their respective letters/dates), it pulls the information into Word.

Something like the following table:
[image]

How can I if one number is the same, only pull one of those numbers (in this case, just 1 row #) and its respective letters and dates for each one, all within one.

Something like this, where it will basically paste the Excel rows to the already made form by filling in the blanks. I want to see if it would be possible to make a new form with each row, while also including the multiple rows (the 3, 3, 3 with their respective letters and whatnot) like you did in one of the pictures.
For the picture below, the left is Word, the form that will be filled out by the Excel rows.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this solution I'm using Excel Tables (`ListObjects`) instead of Excel Range, because it's easier to convert it to an array with the `DataBodyRange` property. Open your Excel file, select the range containing your data and click the `Format As Table dropdown` menu in the `Home` tab, select one of the styles. In the Format As Table window, select the `My table has headers` checkbox, then click `OK`. Save and close it, and go back to Word.

I updated the original code and now it create `Bookmarks` objects to be used as reference points for placing the tables afterwards. Then it generates separate Word tables for each Excel row, and when the value in the first column is repeated, it's placed in the previous table instead.

```
Sub CreateForm()

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ThisDocument.Path & "\TestFile.xlsx")
    
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
    Dim arrTable As Variant
    arrTable = ws.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim i, previousNumber As Integer
    
    'Create empty paragraphs to be used as reference
    'spots for the tables
    For i = 1 To ws.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.Bookmarks.Add "Table" & i
    Next
    
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    
    For i = LBound(arrTable) To UBound(arrTable)
        If previousNumber <> arrTable(i, 1) Then
            Set rng = ThisDocument.Bookmarks("Table" & i).Range
            Set tbl = ThisDocument.Tables.Add(rng, 2, 3)
            
            'Header row
            tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter "Row:"
            tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.InsertAfter "Letter:"
            tbl.Cell(1, 3).Range.InsertAfter "Date:"
            tbl.Rows(1).Range.Bold = True
            tbl.Borders.Enable = True
            
            'Detail row
            tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertAfter arrTable(i, 1)
            tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.InsertAfter arrTable(i, 2)
            tbl.Cell(2, 3).Range.InsertAfter arrTable(i, 3)
        Else
            'Removes the extra paragraph and bookmark since the
            'current row will be placed in the previous table
            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Table" & i
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            ThisDocument.Bookmarks("Table" & i).Delete
            
            tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & arrTable(i, 2)
            tbl.Cell(2, 3).Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & arrTable(i, 3)
        End If
        
        previousNumber = arrTable(i, 1)
    Next
    
    wb.Close
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

You can see the results after running this code in the image below:

[image: Screenshot of the results.]

Comment: Ricardo, this is phenomenal. Thank you so much. For my project, I was trying to add it to an existing form on word. But, it will need to be a row (1,1..2..3..4..etc) per form, unless the number repeats itself. Is it possible to insert the "Range.InsertAfter" in a specific spot of a given form on word?

Comment: So basically I will import data into an excel file that will look like the example I posted. I want to make it to where each actual row on the Excel file will be formatted into a form on Word. Is this a possibility with the CreateForm code? Thanks again

Comment: @Codewriter123 just to clarify, by "form" you mean a table in Word with the first row being the reader and the second row being the row data from Excel, repeating all rows with the same number in this same "form". Is that correct?

Comment: @Codewriter123 regarding your question about `Range.InsertAfter`, yes you can specify the specific spot in several ways: by the character position within the document, in a specific paragraph, using bookmarks and almost any object present in the document.

Comment: @Codewriter123 I updated the code in my original answer, now including the formatting and generating separate tables for each Excel row. I used `Bookmarks` to create reference points for placing the tables.

Comment: I really can't thank you enough for all your help, you're amazing! The form that I was referring to is a form that I created that is a full page. Basically all that information will be inserted on the form. It will have space to include more information, as well as comments and whatnot. But the main idea I was trying to implement was making a form for each table from excel.
Is there a way to create a new word document for every row? I'm trying to create a form for every row, so each row will have it's own form and so on. I will post a picture of the form I am referring to here in a bit.Thanks

Comment: I have edited my original post and included a picture of a 'form' I was thinking about. Thanks again for everything, you're a bad*ss